# How to quote a book that has a quote in the text that I'm quoting?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, style-manuals, mla

I'm trying to quote this in my paper:

> despite the universal desire to return to "normal," things changed

How would I quote this in MLA? Would I substitute the double quotations for single, or use double quotes for everything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MLA guidelines](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/03/):

> "Use single quotation marks to enclose quotes within another quotation."

Thus:

> "despite the universal desire to return to 'normal,' things changed"